# Почему std::find возвращает указатель?

Tags: c++, указатели, stl, дизайн-языка

Зачем в методе `find()` используется указатель. То есть вот в этом примере

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::find
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  // using std::find with array and pointer:
  int myints[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
  int * p;

  p = std::find (myints, myints+4, 30);
  if (p != myints+4)
    std::cout << "Element found in myints: " << *p << '\n';
  else
    std::cout << "Element not found in myints\n";
```

зачем использовать именно указатель p, а не просто переменную p. Мы же не собираемся никак менять элемент массива. Нам просто нужно поискать его в массиве и все. Почему нельзя это сделать без указателя? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) ищет в диапазоне `[first, last)`(`last` не включается) возвращает `last`, если ничего не найдено

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Здравствуйте! А почему после просьбы "найдите в толпе человека с
> красной шапкой" вы пальцем указываете на этого человека, а не
> отвечаете "человек с красной шапочкой"?..

Принимает любой тип, который ведет себя как указатель  (`итератор для чтения` ) и возвращает его(в данном случаи указатель). Это обобщенный алгоритм, и для него логична команда *"отсюда до сюда найти это"*. Алгоритм находит и "говорит", что нашел его `в этом месте` (возвращает итератор, указывающий на это место) или не нашел(возвращает итератор, указывающий за конец последовательности.

Иначе и не построишь логику такого рода команды и выполнения, потому что, если алгоритм каким то образом  просто сообщит о том, что нашел, то останется вопрос: "а в каком месте?". Еще хуже, если он вернет значение(а какое значение вернуть, чтобы вы знали, что он *не нашел*? А если нашел, зачем вам нужно это значение, если оно и так у вас есть?).  А зная место, все вопросы исчерпаны.

Answer (score 14):

1. То, что ты в конкретном примере чего-то делать не собираешься, не означает, что это не нужно. То, что возвращает `find` может использоваться и для изменения значения, и даже для изменения контейнера - например, обрезать вектор после или перед найденным элементом. А ещё можно что-то делать с соседними элементами.
2. Даже если представить, что по некоторой причине завелись две функции - одна ищет указатель (а вообще-то она шаблонная и указатель - это твой вариант, а там может быть любой итератор), а другая - значение, то со значением возникает проблема. Надо как-то уметь отличать ситуацию, когда значение найдено от ситуации, когда оно не найдено. Поскольку мы можем искать любое значение, то надо каким-то образом обеспечить возможность возврата на одно значение больше, чем вмещает используемый тип. Например, при считывании файла нормальные символы вмещаются в char, а getc возвращает int чтобы суметь предоставить EOF вне допустимого диапазона char. Очевидно, что для произвольного типа это сделать затруднительно и чуть ли не единственным вариантом станет возвращать структуру с найденным значением и флагом. Стоп. Структуру с найденным значением? Но не копировать же в неё значение? Тогда структуру с указателем и флагом? А нафига нам теперь флаг, если сам указатель можно использовать для того, чтобы показать, что ничего не найдено?
3. Ну и конкретно про find. Ты ему передаёшь число 30. Если представить, что он вернёт тебе те же самые 30, то нафига тебе это надо? Функция, которая принимает пару итераторов и возвращает свой третий аргумент?
4. А в твоём коде можно заменить find на count, тогда число можно сразу использовать в качестве флага. Впрочем, формально производительность этого кода будет хуже, если только компилятор не догадается что-нибудь заинлайнить и выкинуть лишнее, так что я бы оставил find.

Comment: Есть еще `std::any_of`, который вернет истину, если хотя бы для одного элемента предикат вернет `true`.

Comment: @Croessmah, но ему нужен предикат, то в данном случае менее удобно.

Answer (score 2):

Читаем в документации:

*template <class InputIterator, class T>    InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val);
Find value in range Returns an iterator to the first element in the range [first,last) that compares equal to val. If no such element is found, the function returns last.*

Т.е., метод возвращает итератор элемента, это не совсем указатель. А сделано так для того, чтобы найдя нужный элемент, была возможность перейти к следующему, либо предыдущему элементу. Если бы метод find() возвращал непосредственно значение элемента, то тогда его функционал этим бы и ограничился. Всё ради расширенных возможностей, как-то так. Надеюсь, я правильно уловил суть вопроса...

Comment: так а зачем, найдя нужный элемент, переходить к следующему или предыдущему? разве суть find не в том, чтобы просто проверить, есть ли в массиве конкретный элемент, а если есть, то заканчивать find, а не переходить к следующему или предыдущему?

Comment: нет, суть метода find() - найти элемент и его позицию в массиве, а не просто проверить, есть ли он там. Такой подход существенно расширяет спектр задач, в которых он может быть применён.

Comment: но все равно, после того, как он находит этот элемент, он останавливается, а не переходит к следующему элементу.

Comment: Ну так запустить его дальше искать, ++ к итератору и на 2 круг.